# libprotobuf FATAL Error seen even though I have correct libprotoc version installed

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, tcp

I have installed a C++ based software called remy which uses libprotoc. When I run the tool I get the following error complaining about the installed Protocol Buffer version even though I have the correct one installed. Can someone kindly help resolve the issue.I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.1.

*$./remy2.tcl

[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:72] **This program was compiled against version 2.4.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (2.6.1).**  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "tcp/remy/dna.pb.cc".)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  This program was compiled against version 2.4.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (2.6.1).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "tcp/remy/dna.pb.cc".)

Segmentation fault (core dumped)*

*$ protoc --version*
**libprotoc 2.4.1**

Comment: you've either overwritten the shared libraries in /usr/local/lib or LDPATH is pointing somewhere strange and you're picking up the wrong libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I tried uninstalling 2.4.1 and reinstalling it again. But before that I removed the libprotobuf* files under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ . This seems to have resolved the issue