# How to isolate GTK3 google protobuf 2.6.1 dependency from Google protobuf 3.8.0 for rest of Cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, gtk3

## TL;DR

I have run into a dependency issue with mismatched versions of Google Protobufs.

## END TL;DR

I have been using Google protobufs for a while now and I have run into a strange dilemma. I have installed version `3.8.0` from source and I use it in a few projects. I am now trying to do a project that uses `GTK3` for the GUI. I have been trying to run my program but I keep running into this error:

```
./runserver.sh 
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:86] This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.8.0).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "/build/mir-O8_xaj/mir-0.26.3+16.04.20170605/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.8.0).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "/build/mir-O8_xaj/mir-0.26.3+16.04.20170605/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
./runserver.sh: line 4:  8205 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./build/src/thechatroom server
```

I understand that I need the correct version installed or it won't work. The issue is that, now matter what I do (reading the variable `Protobuf_VERSION` in CMake or `protoc --version` on the terminal), I always show version `3.8.0` as the correct version.
According to these 3 questions (and the comments in those answers), this is because `GTK3` depends on an older version of Google Protobufs.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503347/how-to-compile-opencv-with-gtk-2-x-rather-than-gtk3-x
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964212/conflict-protobuf-version-when-using-opencv-and-tensorflow-c
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49823114/google-protobuf-dependency-collision
```

I should mention that I am getting the [opposite issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684581/libprotobuf-fatal-error-seen-even-though-i-have-correct-libprotoc-version-instal?rq=1) as this person: I detect the new version on mine.

So, my question is, how do I isolate the older version (2.6.1) for `GTK3` and use the newer version (3.8.0) for everything else in CMake?

Comment: I'd like to have an update on this issue...